# How to involk jquery function and get client id and pass array as parameter

Tags: jquery, client

I have a jquery doubt . Following is the function . I am using jquery-2.0.3.js . 
i want to wrie

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 function anyfunction(sender, txtid) {


}

});
```

But it gives error . Why ?

second thing is

i want to pass array as argument to function. How ?

```
      <input id="Text7" type="text" /><input id="Button7" type="button" 
        value="button" onclick="anyfunction(this,'Text7')" /></p>


 function anyfunction(sender, txtid) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

    var ctrl = $(sender).attr('id');      // get client id of control who fire event
    $('#' + ctrl)[0].focus();             // It is just for example . 

    // or

    var id1 = $("[id$='" + txtid + "']"); // get ref of any control on document using id .
    $(id1).focus();

});

}
```

Comment: error is -   
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: First, try removing the `$(document).ready()`. Generally, you don't define functions inside `$(document).ready()`, and you don't put `$(document).ready()` inside function definitions.

Comment: It throw error
error is - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$('#' + ctrl)[0].focus();
```

should be:

```
$('#' + ctrl).focus();
```

`$(...)` returns a jQuery object, `$(...)[0]` extracts the corresponding DOM object from the jQuery object. Since `focus()` is a jQuery function, it should be applied to the jQuery object.

Your second version looks like it should work. It can also be written as:

```
id1.focus();
```

since `id1` is a jQuery object. It will work as is because when jQuery is given a jQuery object, it simply returns it, so there's no harm (except a little performance impact) from extra wrapping.

I don't understand what you mean about passing an array to the function. `this` is a DOM object, `'Text7'` is a string, neither of them is an array.

Comment: function anyfunction(sender, txtid , param ) {
x = param.item(0,'key1');
}